# How did Vietnam do era names prior to the reign of emperor Gia Long?

Tags: vietnam

How did Vietnamese era names work before the "One reign, One era name" system? I know starting with Gia Long they had era name defined by the ruler (Gia Long to Bao Dai), but before that it was more complicated with there being multiple eras during one rule. For instance, Emperor Le Anh Tong had the Thuan Binh (1548-1556), Thien Huu (1556-1557), Chinh Tri (1558-1571) and Hong Phuc (1572-1573) eras.

How exactly did they decide where an era started and ended without using the incumbent Emperor to decide it?

Research effort: I think the Vietnamese era name changes on the year (or the next year) a monarch ascended to the throne. Before that, the monarch will continue the previous era name. Chaging the era name later for a monarch is optional, but if the monarch did so, it would be reset to the 1st year of that era name. Many of the Vietnamese era name changed in the 1st year of the 1st lunar month (regardless era name change due to a monarch (re-)ascended to the throne or other reasons [for the second era name or later era name]), slightly different from the one in Japan which is broadly recorded (which only changed the era name on the 1st day of the 1st lunar month for one time, Ten'ō [天應/天応, 781/1-782/8]).

For example: era names of Le Thai Tong worked as the following:

Le Thai Tong
(r. 20 October 1433 - 7 September 1442)

Thuan Thien [順天] (20 October 1433 - 8 Febraury 1434) [9/8 to 12/29 of 1433 in Vietnamese lunar calendar] - Continued the usage of his father's era name, 6th year of Thuan Thien

Thieu Binh [紹平] (9 February 1434 - 2 February 1440) [1434/1/1 to 1439/12/29 in Vietnamese lunar calendar] - Era name changed to mark Le Thai Tong's reign, changed on 1/1 of lunar calendar, 1st-6th year of Thieu Binh

Dai Bao [大寶] (3 February 1440 - 3 September 1442?) [1440/1/1 to 1442/7/29 in Vietnamese lunar calendar] - Era name changed on 1/1 of lunar calendar, 1st-3rd year of Dai Bao

Duy Ninh [維寧] (?) (4 September 1442? - 7 September 1442) [8/1 to 8/4 of 1442 in Vietnamese lunar calendar] - Mentioned in Li Zhaoluo's *Ji Yuan Bian* (纪元编), said it is from the book *Lei Ju Kao* (类聚考). This era name possibly does not exist and the era name might still be Dai Bao. 1st year of Duy Ninh [See Chinese Wikipedia]